# How to let ogr/gdal CreateLayer() create a `geom` field instead of `wkb_geometry`?

Tags: ogr, python-3, gdal-python-binding

When creating a new table (PostGIS) using OGR/GDAL (2.1+), is there a way to select a specific name for the geometry field (such as `geom`), rather than using the default name?

I created a new table via python3 ogr/grdal liek this:

```
ds = gdal.OpenEx(connection_string, gdal.OF_VECTOR | gdal.OF_UPDATE)
lyr = ds.CreateLayer( "mylayer", XXX, ogr.wkbLineString)
```

The problem is that I can't find a parameter to specify the name of the geometry field, only its type. In the table created, the geometry field seems to be called `wkb_geometry` by default:

```
wkb_geometry geometry(LineString,26945)
```

Is there a parameter or option to let `CreateLayer()` use a different name such as `geom`?

Related question: [Use Postgis to convert wkb_geometry data type to geom datatype](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174878)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.DataSource-class.html#CreateLayer, CreateLayer support also "options" which are "None" by default.

> The papszOptions argument can be used to control driver specific
>   creation options. These options are normally documented in the format
>   specific documentation.

Usage example for PostgeSQL and Python can be found from the GDAL autotest script https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/autotest/ogr/ogr_pg.py

See for example row 5191:

```
lyr = gdaltest.pg_ds.CreateLayer('ogr_pg_82', geom_type = ogr.wkbNone, options = ['GEOMETRY_NAME=another_name'])
```