# Specify geom field name with ogr2ogr: gdb to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr

I use the following `ogr2ogr` command to import my open file geodatabase into PostgreSQL.

```
# Note, I use the -append because I am adding to preexisting tables with the same structure
ogr2ogr -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=database host=localhost user=username password=password" my.gdb
```

This works just fine, but it always specifies the geometry field as `wkb_geometry`, and I'd like it to be `geom` as is the usual convention. I thought this might be controlled by the `-geomfield` option, but it seems that this is the not the correct flag (the documentation is too vague for me to be sure though).

If it was just one geodatabase, I could simply loop through and rename all the columns to `geom`, but since I will be appending multiple databases together that won't work.

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions.

Comment: *Note, I use the -append because I am adding to preexisting tables with the same structure* what is the field called in the table that you're appending too.

Comment: @EvanCaroll Actually what I first do is upload First.gdb without the `-append` then add the others. So the geom field in the tables is `wkb_geometry` by default.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the help in `ogr2ogr --long-usage`, there is layer creation option:

> -lco  NAME=VALUE: Layer creation option (format specific)

You can use the [driver specific option](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html) `GEOMETRY_NAME=geom` to

> Set name of geometry column in new table

as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=database host=localhost user=username password=password" my.gdb
```

See related question [How to let ogr/gdal CreateLayer() create a `geom` field instead of `wkb_geometry`?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251905).

Comment: This works, however, I am having trouble adding the laundered option to `-lco`. Is there some trick to passing multiple parameters to `-lco`?
 `ogr2ogr -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom LAUNDER=NO -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=database schemas=schema" my.gdb`

Comment: Got it, turns out you need to specify `-lco` before each individual option.